# Indian citizen, J1 Tax Exempt in USA. Do I pay India taxes for US income?

Tags: j-visa, tax-treaties

I am an Indian citizen and holding J1-research scholar and has been approved for tax exemption in USA for 24 months under Article 22 Tax Treaty. Do I need to pay taxes for the US income in India? Appreciate your help.